# Is it possible to copy files from text mode to gui mode or vice versa?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, copy-paste, tty

I use the `xclip-copyfile <src-file>` command to copy files, and use the `xclip-pastefile <dst-file>` command to paste the file, but I want to paste it into gui mode (browser) for a backup purpose e.g., google drive.